# Code crashes. Trying to remove characters from char array C

Tags: c++, arrays, truncation, strncpy

I am basically trying to store everything after a certain index in the array.

For example, I want to store a name which is declared as `char name[10]`. If the user inputs in say `15` characters, it will ignore the first five characters and store the rest in the char array, however, my program crashes.

This is my code

```
char name[10];
cout<< "Starting position:" << endl;
cin >> startPos;
for(int i= startPos; i< startPos+10; i++)
{
  cout << i << endl; // THIS WORKS
  cout << i-startPos << endl; // THIS WORKS
  name[i-startPos] = name[i]; // THIS CRASHES
}
```

For example, if my name was `McStevesonse`, I want the program to just store everything from the 3rd position, so the end result is `Stevesonse`

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me fix this crash.

Thanks

Comment: If `name` declared as `name[10]`, and `startPos > 0`, then `i` will get larger than 10, and so `name[i]` will access beyond the allocated space. The code you posted is not very clear in that context, as you describe half of it by words, not in the code.

Comment: How do you store the 15 characters of the user input into the `char name[10]` variable? When you know the answer to this question, you will understand what the problem is. Unfortunately, this part of your program is not in your question, so I cannot answer this question. However, I can tell you that it is impossible to store 15 characters into an array of 10 `char`s without causing "undefined behavior" which often translates to crashes later on.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't seem to pertain to the question you've asked. `If the user inputs in say 15 characters ...`; I don't see your program asking for the user's name anywhere. Please rephrase your question and/or include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `i` is equal to 3. In the last iteration of the loop, `i` is now equal to 12, so substituting 12 in for `i`, your last line reads

```
name[12-startPos] = name[12];
```

`name[12]` is out of bounds of the array. Based on what you have shown so far, there is nothing but garbage stored in `name` anyway before you start doing this assignment, so all you're doing is reorganizing garbage in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Please in future: post full compilable example.
A simple answer is that your array *maybe* is out of bound, since you don't provide full example its hard to know exactly.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int new_length, startPos;
int length = 15;
char name[15]= "McStevesonse";

cout<< "Starting position:" << endl;
cin >> startPos;
if(new_length <1){ // you need to check for negative or zero value!!!
    cout << "max starting point is " <<length-1 << endl;
    return -1;
}
new_length=length-startPos;
char newname[new_length];
for(int i= 0; i<new_length; i++){
  newname[i] = name[i+startPos]; // THIS CRASHES
}
cout << "old name: " <<  name << " new name: " << newname << endl;
return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To put it simply, change this:**

```
for(int i= startPos; i< startPos+10; i++)
```

**To this:**

```
for(int i= startPos; i<10; i++)
```

You should be fine with that.

**Explanation:**

At some point, when you use the your old loop, this `name[i-startPos] = name[i]` would eventually reach an array index out of bounds and causes the crash.

**Don't forget to clean up/hide the garbage:**
Doing so, would cause the output to produce some kind of garbage outputs. If you got a character array of *`'ABCDEFGHIJ'`*, and have chosen 3 as the starting position, the array would be arranged to *`'DEFGHIJHIJ'`*. In your output, you should atleast hide the excess characters, or remove by placing `\0`'s